# Boot login loop 18.04

Tags: login, home-directory

I am having the same issue stated elsewhere concerning a loop at login. I boot up my machine, enter my password, the screen goes black, and returns to login.  I can access a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. But even from the terminal, I cannot access the contents of my home folder. None of it is there. Instead there's a README file stating my data has been moved to protect it.

[image: files in home]

I’m posting this because none of the other solutions apply, since they require access to one's home folder contents, and I have none.

Prior to this I had error messages when updating concerning RESUME and some Dynamsoft check manager??, but I cannot share them with you because I copied them to notes, and I cannot access my data. I’m not sure if it’s related.

It’s sort of urgent now, as I need my data for work.

When I login from terminal, it produces this repeating error:

```
certutil: function failed: SEC_ERROR_BAD_DATABASE: security library: bad database
```

It repeats on each line until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

When I update my system using the terminal `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` once it's complete, it announces the following:

```
[1]+ Exit 130   opt/dynamsoft/DynamsoftService/DynamsoftCertCheckMgr
```

(The “1” above should be formatted with brackets)

I have tried the following:

1. I went into the RESUME file and changed it to equal none. This did not correct the RESUME error. I then changed it to the swap UUID. Still no change in RESUME error message. After the next update, the login loop began.
2. I have uninstalled dynamsoftservice. Still no change in login loop. But in terminal, I’m no longer getting “bad database" error messages. I also could not find any purpose for this program online, aside from scanning documents (TWAIN).
3. I have uninstalled VirtualBox, because a similar issue suggested it as a possible culprit. I had installed it just previous to the problem I’m having.
4. The README file shown in the picture above states that this directory had been unmounted to protect my data. It instructs me to click on “Access Your Private Data” from the GUI (I have no access, due to login loop) OR run encryptfs-mount-private from command line. I did that and it gives the following message:

   ```
   /usr/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private: 69: /usr/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private: /sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private: not found
   ```

   (all on one line)

Answer (score 1):

I have finally accessed my data. The instructions in the README file stating to use encryptfs-mount-private DO NOT WORK. You have to use encryptfs-recover-private

I am still unable to login via the GUI.

Comment: Did you finally solve the GUI issue?

Comment: No.  I had to reinstall.  But I did find out what the problem was.  I had run out of hard drive space.  My machine is partitioned between Ubuntu and Windows 7.  I keep a chunk of unused space open between them, and add space as each needs.  I had neglected to add space to the Ubuntu side.  My apologies for not updating.  Thank you for asking.